# Swift: File exists but cannot be deleted because it doesn't exist

Tags: swift, file, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory, nserror

I'm trying to delete a file from the Documents dir. `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dataUrl.path!)` returns `true`, which should mean that the file exists, but trying to delete it throws an error which says `No such file or directory`

My code:

```
let directoryUrl = FileManager.default().urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask).first!
let pathComponent = "data.zip"

let dataUrl =  try! directoryUrl.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)

let fileManager = FileManager.default()

do {
    do {
        let filelist = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryUrl.path!)

        for filename in filelist {
            print(filename)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dataUrl!) {
        print("File exists")
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: dataUrl.path)
        print("Deleted existing data")
    } else {
        print("File does not exist")
    }
} catch {
    print("Could not delete data: \(error)")
}
```

My console output:

```
data.zip // File exists when trying to print it
File exists
Could not delete timetables: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "data.zip") couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=Optional("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4CA64C91-219E-49DE-9039-6BA71640A570/Documents/data.zip"), NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x17024bee0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Comment: Why argument to `fileExists(atPath:` is `dataUrl`, whereas argument to `removeItem(atPath:` is `dataUrl.path`?

Comment: There is a confusion `timetables.zip` vs. `data.zip`. Where does `timetables` come from?

Comment: Assuming your arguments to the calls are correct (and the above comments seem to indicate they're *not*), this is still a [time-of-check-time-of-use bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)  Yes.  This bug has a name and even a Wikipedia page.  While a file may exist when you check for existence, it can be deleted by another process by the time you try to delete it.  If you want to delete a file - just delete it.  If the delete fails because it's already gone, it's not a problem.

Comment: @mouviciel what is the correct argument to use?

Comment: @vadian sorry, fixed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is for sure not that bug, as the next time I run the app I get the same output.

Comment: I only raise the apparent inconsistency. You should read [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html) to find out whether this is correct or not.